# How to graphically depict the possible solutions of a quadratic equation

Tags: roots, graphing-functions, quadratics

I have the following quadratic equation :

$$am^2 + bm + (c_1^2 +c_2^2) =0,$$
where the solution is given by

$$m = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(c_1^2+c_2^2)}}{2a}.$$ Here, $\Delta>0$.

Thus I have two real roots What I would like to do is to graphically depict possible solutions based on the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Here, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two components of a vector and are real numbers.

Can anyone help me out with this? And is it possible to do that?

Comment: There is a formula for the two (positive) solutions $m_{1,2}$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I guess here, both the solutions might not be positive.  Most likely one is positive and other one is negative.

Comment: Add the condition that the discriminant is positive. This should give you a condition on the coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by "depict possible solutions"?

Comment: @TodorMarkov I would like to plot the possible  values of m as a function of $c_1$ and $c_2$ or $b$.

Comment: if $a>0$, then both roots will be positive or both roots will be negative. Else if $a<0$, one root will be negative and the other will be positive.

Comment: The solution is clearly a function of $4$ unknowns. Even if you want to treat $a,b$ as constant you still have a function of $2$ variable, which only can be plotted in 3D.

Comment: @YiFan Thanks. If we consider $c_1 =c_2 = c$ (just for argument sake), then we might get a plot $m$ vs $c_1$.

Comment: @newstudent Yes, you can. Or, you can just consider $a,b,c_1$ all to be constant and plot $m(c_2)$. It's entirely your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + (c_1^2 +c_2^2)$.

If $\Delta \gt 0$, then

(1) $f(x) = 0$ has two real roots ($\alpha$ and $\beta$, say) and this implies the graph of $y = f(x)$ will cut the x-axis at two distinct points [$(\alpha, 0)$ and $(\beta, 0)$].

(2) $b^2 \gt 4a(c_1^2 + c_2^2)$. From $\dfrac {b^2 }{4a }\gt c_1^2 + c_2^2$, we can say $a \gt 0$. This further means the graph of $y = f(x)$ concaves upward. Since $\alpha \times \beta = \dfrac {c_1^2 + c_2^2}{a}$, which is positive, the two points will lie on the same side of the y-axis (either left or right but not both).

Since $f(0) = (c_1^2 +c_2^2) \gt 0$, $y = f(x)$ passes through $(0, k)$ where $k = c_1^2 +c_2^2$, which is positive.

Because we know nothing about the sign of b, there are two possible solutions for the plot as shown.

[image]

Even from the fact that the minimum occurs at $(\dfrac {-b}{2a}, f[\dfrac {-b}{2a}])$ with $f[\dfrac {-b}{2a}] < 0$, we can at the most deduce $\dfrac {(c_1^2 + c_2^2)}{a} < (\dfrac {-b}{2a})^2$. But we still cannot make any further deduction.